# #1193 - Unknown system variable 'id'

Tags: mysql

spend 8 hours to examine this issue, but have no any result,can someone said what wrong?

```
>SELECT id FROM posts AS post_id;SET categories.id  AS category_id;  
>SELECT title, contents, date_posted, categories, name FROM posts INNER JOIN 
>categories ON categories, id = posts, cat_id ORDER BY id DESC
```

and got an error
$ #1193 - Unknown system variable 'id'

I also try something like this:

```
>SELECT id FROM posts AS post_id;  
>SELECT id FROM categories AS category_id;  
>SELECT COALESCE (title, contents, date_posted, categories, name) 
>FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories, id = posts, cat_id
>ORDER BY id DESC
```

And a lot of other staffs which don't work  correctly.

Working query:

```
 >SELECT posts . p_id AS post_id, categories . c_id AS category_id,  
    >title, contents, date_posted, categories . name   
    >FROM posts  
    >INNER JOIN categories ON categories . c_id = posts . cat_id  
    >ORDER BY posts.p_id DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry for bad English)

Comment: `ON categories, id`?? You mean `ON categories.id`

Comment: No  i mean  that got to join 2 tables ID, from 'categories', and from 'posts', and its ID's.

Comment: Sorry, you was wright) Thanks)

Comment: Can you paste the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the variable name id in your database to something else. id is a reserved name.

Comment: Thank You,it but doesn't help, just an error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'c_id'...              New code looks  :      >SELECT id FROM posts AS post_id; SET categories.c_id  AS category_id; 
SELECT title, contents, date_posted, categories, name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories, c_id = posts, cat_id

Comment: sorry can't get how to write a code in comments + They add the TRIM func)

Comment: @VitaliySobol Make sure you are changing the ID in the database, and in the code that you are selecting from the database.

Comment: Thank you for option, but now it can't find 'c_id' (renamed 'id'). First, i want to perform request in sql, and if it works, then make changes in code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your query then use as per below-

```
SELECT pst.id AS post_id,cat.id AS category_id, title, contents, date_posted, categories, NAME 
FROM posts AS pst 
INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = pst.cat_id 
ORDER BY pst.id DESC;
```

Note: You may do order by based on cat.id then change accordingly.

Comment: Thank You for advise, but new error appear >#1054 - Unknown column 'categories' in 'field list'

Comment: Maybe some one knows any synonyms for SELECT, and FROM which do the same in MySQL? Than i could try to rewrite a code... Because i can't find any posts on this theme.

Comment: actually I took columns from your query, it seems either there is no categories column in your any table or exist in both tables, if it exists in both tables then use alias before it suppose it belong to categories then use cat.categories if it does not exists in any table then remove this column from table.

Comment: Thank you for advise,but in both tables are only 'id' as primary key,other titles not repeating... This query should to  displayed on the main page the  info from both tables(maybe it can help). So maybe you can give me advise how to do this query in other way. Thank you

Comment: just put alias with all fields and check, suppose title belong to categories table then use cat.title, same for categories use it cat.categories...even I doubt that there will be any column 'categories' in any table...so remove if it is not a column...

Comment: I try to do some another way, and it works )))))) If some One interesting, i put the answer in question...Thank you all for help

Comment: same solution I provided you but you mentioned categories and name seperate fields distinguished by comman in your question that was the problem as you should use cat.name in my query. and in your question category primary key mentioned as id while it is c_id, so you need to change accordingly cat.c_id=pst.cat_id...further as you have got solution so enjoy cheers...